# froala custom drop down to insert html snippet

Tags: jquery, html, wysiwyg

I'm trying to make a custom dropdown in froala wysiwyg html editor and it works nicely.

Is it possible to insert a snippet of HTML when I click the item inside the dropdown? How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You have to call the `insertHTML` method. See http://jsbin.com/leheruku/4/.

```
customDropdowns: {
  my_dropdown: {
    title: 'Dropdown',
    icon: {
      type: 'font',
      value: 'fa fa-star'
    },
    options: {
      'Insert HTML': function(){
        $('#edit').editable('insertHTML', 'your custom HTML');
      }
    }
  }
}
```